# jQuery / JavaScript checkbox display the number of checked checkboxes in multiple and single selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Please I want to display the number of the checked checkboxes in this code.
If i check the global checkbox (Select All) and also when I check each one.

Here is my code below. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#checkbox-global').click(function(){

    $('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       $('.loaded').show(1000);
    else
      $('.loaded').hide(1000);
});

$('.checkbox-group').change(function(){
    $('#count').text($(".checkbox-group:checked").length); // Show Number of counts of checkboxes
    var checkedLength =  $('.checkbox-group:checked').length;

    if(checkedLength > 0)
      $('.loaded').show(1000);
    else
     $('.loaded').hide(1000);
});
```

});

```
   <div class="loaded">RESTORE | DELETE</div>
            <p id="count"></p>

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-global" class="checkbox-group">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group">
```

Comment: I guess you could use: `$('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', this.checked).first().triggerHandler('change');` And instead of `click` event, use `change`. FYI, `$(this).is(':checked')` is just more boring way to write `this.checked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function updateCheckedCount() {
    $("#count").html($(".checkbox-group:not(#checkbox-global):checked").length);
}

$("#checkbox-global").on("change", function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".checkbox-group").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $(".checkbox-group").removeAttr("checked");
    }
    updateCheckedCount();
});

$(".checkbox-group").on("change", function() {
    if(!$("#checkbox-global").is(":checked") && $(".checkbox-group:not(#checkbox-global)").length == $(".checkbox-group:not(#checkbox-global):checked").length) {
        $("#checkbox-global").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
    updateCheckedCount();
});

updateCheckedCount();
```

This is an idea, you should optimize this code. For example, it will be a good idea change the #checkbox-global class checkbox-group to avoid conflicts when you are selecting.

Comment: Thanks man... It didn't work at first but i replaced the attr(); with .prop(); and it worked :). You did it man !

Comment: But I had a div displaying on click of global and each checkbox... the div is no more displaying.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is programmatically better use prop than attr to read and set checked value:
.prop("checked") ?
.prop("checked", true)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#checkbox-global').click(function() {

    $('.checkbox-group').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $('.loaded').show(1000);
    else
        $('.loaded').hide(1000);

    $(".checkbox-group").trigger("change");
});
$('.checkbox-group').change(function() {
    $('#count').text($(".checkbox-group:checked").length); // Show Number of counts of checkboxes
    var checkedLength = $('.checkbox-group:checked').length;

    if (checkedLength > 0)
        $('.loaded').show(1000);
    else
        $('.loaded').hide(1000);
});
});
```

Just add the trigger event as I have added to your existing code. Hope this will work for you!
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kb4rq36L/

Comment: Awesome, you did it !, But the only problem is that the count also (counts) the global checkbox.

I have 7 checkboxes there, I only use the global checkbox to toggle the chekbox-group (Select all) and should not be counted as one.

I really appreciate you guys, thanks in advance !